# Todas as pastas do FontAwesome são úteis?

Tags: css, font-awesome

Eu uso o Font Awesome 5.2 apenas essa forma de inserir os ícones:

```html
<i class="fab fa-500px"></i>
```

Gostaria de saber se para isso é necessário deixar no projeto todas essas pastas e arquivos que vem no arquivo baixado do site, tem uma pasta SVG lotada de arquivos e não sei se realmente estão sendo utilizados.

[image: as pastas atuais são essas]

Comment: Esse é um "pack" de desenvolvimento, vc não precisa dele, a não ser que vc queira fazer customizações, ou um fallback caso o browser não suporte SVG, ele vai usar a font no formato OTF. Ai vc vai precisar das pastas webfonts e css. Lei mais aqui https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

Comment: Muito obrigado @hugocsl Agora ficou claro.

Answer (score 3):

Não necessariamente você pode utilizar só o arquivo all.js que ele irá funcionar normalmente.

As outras pastas e arquivos você pode retirar do seu projeto.